# MS Visio - Create/Insert a new Page/Tab in C#

Tags: c#, visio

I have searched nearly everywhere, but cannot find a way of creating/inserting a new Page/Tab in C# within a Visio document.  I recorded a VB Macro of creating a new page within a document, and it is really simple there.  However, I am using C# and cannot find the right commnands.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your VBA Macro code

Comment: The VBA code is simple:

Comment: Then post it, the C# code will be more or less the same

Comment: The VBA code is simple:
  Dim vsoPage1 as Visio.Page
  Set vsoPage1 = ActiveDocument.Pages.Add

I cannot figure out the equivelant in C#:
  Visio.Application flowApp = new Visio.Application;
  Visio.Documents flowDocs = new flowApp.Documents;
  flowDocs.Add("");
  Visio.Page Page1 = flowApp.ActivePage;
  //All code here for Page1
  *Insert new page - Page2
  //All code here for Page2

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the ugly format, I don't know how that happened!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing in C# you will use the same [COM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff769201%28v=office.14%29.aspx) which VBA uses. A simple way to automate Visio using C# is to download and install the [Primary Interop Assembly (PIA)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18346). Then include the reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio in your project. Here is a simple example of using the PIA to manipulate the pages in a Visio document.

```
namespace VisioExample
{
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Start Visio
            Application app = new Application();

            // Create a new document.
            Document doc = app.Documents.Add("");

            // The new document will have one page,
            // get the a reference to it.
            Page page1 = doc.Pages[1];

            // Add a second page.
            Page page2 = doc.Pages.Add();

            // Name the pages. This is what is shown in the page tabs.
            page1.Name = "Abc";
            page2.Name = "Def";

            // Move the second page to the first position in the list of pages.
            page2.Index = 1;                
        }
    }
}
```

To learn about developing solutions you can look at the [Developing Visio Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa245244%28v=office.10%29.aspx) book online.  Download the [Visio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=Visio+Software+Development+Kit), it contains a library of sample code in C#. You could look at "[Visio 2003 Developer's Survival Pack](http://amzn.com/1412011124)" by Graham Wideman. As you found, the macro recorder can show you the API methods you need to call to achieve a task. The [COM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff769201%28v=office.14%29.aspx) used by VBA are the same API you will use in C#, the syntax of the code will differ obviously.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!! Where did you find out how to do this? I spent a long time with Google and could not find a scrap of information compared with this.